# Ampersand inside new command, tabular environment

Tags: tables, xstring, ampersand

I'm trying to define a macro for table headers but unfortunately I'm far from a TeX expert. I should split a list that is delimited with ampersands, format the entries and concatenate it again with ampersands. Splitting the list works but I can't concatenate it with ampersands.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\DLbase}[1]% #1 = comma delimited keywords
{{\saveexpandmode\expandarg%
\StrCut{\noexpand#1}{&}\DLleft\DLright%
\loop% extract keywords from list
\StrCut{\DLright}{&}\DLnext\DLright%
\textbf\DLleft\DLsep%
\edef\DLleft{\DLnext}%
\if\DLright\relax\else\repeat%
\textbf{\DLleft}%
\restoreexpandmode}}

\newcommand{\tabhead}[1]{\def\DLsep{&}\DLbase{#1}\\}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
  \begin{center}
    \caption{Command / Purposes}
    \begin{tabular}{|p{0.3\textwidth}|p{0.6\textwidth}|}
      \hline
      \tabhead{Command & Purpose}
      \hline
      cd & change directory \\
      rm & remove files 
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
  \end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I copied most of the code from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/283809/ampersand-inside-new-command-align-environment) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54941/replacing-ampersands-in-argument).

How do I have to define `\DLbase` and `\DLsep` that this works?

Comment: There are other ways of formatting a row inside a `tabular`. See [An improved `\rowstyle` that takes the cell contents as an argument](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32861/5764) for an example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is always to output all the row before TeX “sees” `&`. It's easy with `expl3`, with `\seq_use:Nn`, that delivers its result “at once”.

The `\tabhead` command has an optional argument for the formatting command, default `\bfseries`. It splits its argument at `&`, then adds the optional argument before items, separating them with `&`, with a trailing `\\`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\tabhead}{ O{\bfseries} m }
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { & } { #2 }
  #1 \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { & #1 } \\
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\caption{Command / Purposes}

\begin{tabular}{|p{0.3\textwidth}|p{0.6\textwidth}|}
\hline
\tabhead{Command & Purpose}
\hline
cd & change directory \\
rm & remove files \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{|p{0.3\textwidth}|p{0.6\textwidth}|}
\hline
\tabhead[\itshape]{Command & Purpose}
\hline
cd & change directory \\
rm & remove files \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Rather than using `xstring` I recommend using the dedicated commands in the [xparse](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xparse) package such as `\SplitList` or `\SplitArgument` to do this. As these commands don't appear to play well with ampersands (I'm sure this could be fixed by playing with the category codes), I have changed `\tabhead` to expect a command separated list:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

% typeset an entry of the header
\newcommand\MakeEntry[1]{\headersep#1\def\headersep{&}}

\DeclareDocumentCommand\tabhead{ > { \SplitList{,}} m }
   {\let\headersep\relax% no & needed for first column
    \ProcessList{#1}{\MakeEntry}\relax\\%
   }

\begin{document}

    \begin{tabular}{|p{0.3\textwidth}|p{0.6\textwidth}|}
      \hline
      \tabhead{Command, Purpose}
      \hline
      cd & change directory \\
      rm & remove files\\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

I've dropped the `center` and `table` environments as they are not necessary for the MWE. This produces the expected output:

[image]

In the definition of `\tabhead` the `>` causes the "input" to be treated as a comma separated list, the entries of which are then passed to `\MakeEntry` by `\ProcessList`. The `\headersep` macro is use to add a `&` separator before every header item except the first.

Comment: Thank you for your solution which works fine when one uses a different delimiter than the ampersand. I couldn't figure out where I should change the catcode. Luckily I don't have to anymore due to egregs solution.